# Прервать ожидание Promise в JavaScript

Tags: promise, phantomjs

Пишу скрипт для *PhantomJS*. Скрипт вызывает функции, находящиеся в контексте страницы и возвращающие *Promise*.

Проблема в том, что страница может быть закрыта или обновлена, в результате чего работа функции будет прервана, а *Phantom* продолжит ждать завершения *Promise*, который никогда не получит результат.

Итого: весь поток виснет.

Если бы все скрипты выполнялись в одном контексте - без проблем - повесил бы `setTimeout` на `resolve/reject` внутри *Promise*, а в данном случае `setTimeout` также будет уничтожен.

Можно ли как-то установить таймаут в *PhantomJS* на завершение *Promise*, созданного на странице и переданного в *Phantom*?

Можно перенести все *промисы* в *Фантом*, но могут возникнуть другие проблемы.

Comment: Там нет события закрытия страницы, на которое можно подвеситься и всем promise сделать reject?

Comment: Точно! Что-то не подумал...

Comment: @etki оформите свой комментарий в виде ответа.